# Selected item in layertree group or layer?

Tags: pyqgis, grouping, qgslayertree

How do I check in PyQgis if the selected item in de QgsLayerTree is a group or a layer. I really can't find the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can check with the `QgsLayerTree.isGroup()` / `.isLayer()` static methods, the `.nodeType()` method, or by using `isinstance()`.

```
p = QgsProject.instance()
root = p.layerTreeRoot()

for c in root.children():
    # node type 0 appears to be a group (also for nested groups)
    print(c.name(), '| nodeType:', c.nodeType())

    # QgsLayerTree helper functions, thanks to @CodeBard for the suggestion
    if QgsLayerTree.isGroup(c):
        print('I am a group')
    elif QgsLayerTree.isLayer(c):
        print('I am a layer')
    
    # or check with isinstance
    if isinstance(c, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        print('I am still a group')
    elif isinstance(c, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
        print('I am still a layer')
```

Output:

```
virtual_layer | nodeType: 1    # virtual layer
I am a layer
I am still a layer
points | nodeType: 1           # geopackage vector layer
I am a layer
I am still a layer
group1 | nodeType: 0           # group
I am a group
I am still a group
OpenStreetMap Mapnik | nodeType: 1  # raster layer
I am a layer
I am still a layer
group4 | nodeType: 0           # group
I am a group
I am still a group
```

Comment: In addition, there are two static helper functions [`QgsLayerTree.isGroup()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTree.html#a8c9f859709d3a9d54db6c87c4ac6f7df) and `QgsLayerTree.isLayer()`, which can also be used to check for group or layer :)

Comment: Thank you! I thought of these originally but I was looking through the QgsLayerTreeLayer methods, and not the QgsLayerTree methods, and consequently couldn't find them. I hope you don't mind that I include them in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to Matt I came up with something like this:

```
cnode = iface.layerTreeView().currentNode()
if cnode.nodeType() == 0:
    for lnode in cnode.children()[::-1]:
        if lnode.nodeType() == 1:   #can be a subgroup
            dosomething(lnode.layerId())
elif cnode.nodeType() == 1:
    dosomething(cnode.layerId())
```